# Getting a specific client from WebSocketCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, websocket

I am writing a websocket handler which should send a message from one client to another.

**CODE**

```
public class SocketHandler : WebSocketHandler
{
    private static WebSocketCollection clients = new WebSocketCollection();

    private int id;

    public override void OnOpen()
    {
        this.id = Convert.ToInt32(Cypher.Decrypt(this.WebSocketContext.QueryString["id"]));
        clients.Add(this);         
    }

    public override void OnMessage(string message)
    {
        //sending code here
    }
}
```

I know if I need to send a message to all connected clients I just need to do:

`clients.Broadcast("message");`

...but what I need is to send to a specific client with specific `Id` assigned to it from query string - let's say `1156`.

How can I get the client with `id=1156` from the clients collection?

I tried using lambda expressions but it's not working. It should be simple... I have done similar things before in LINQ but at this time I am totally lost.

Comment: What did you try with your linq statements?

Comment: @RowlandShaw like `clients.SingleOrDefault(x => x.id == id);` but here **x.id** is not available

Comment: in this line...
this.id = Convert.ToInt32(Cypher.Decrypt(this.WebSocketContext.QueryString["id"]));

Decrypt is not resolving. Can someone tell me what namespace it is in because its not coming up in NEO4j. Thanks

Comment: @JudsonTerrell That is a function of my own class `Cypher`. You don't need to use `Cypher.Decrypt`

Comment: Thanks i just posted a question on how to get the querystring param of "id" if you want to answer it for me.

Comment: @JudsonTerrell I checked out your que, Whats wrong with the current way?

Comment: Actually you are right. The answer posted below works just fine. ie:clients.SingleOrDefault(r => ((SocketHandler)r).id == 1156).Send("Hey 1156!");

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally managed to search through clients for a specific client and send the message specifically to him.

```
clients.SingleOrDefault(r => ((SocketHandler)r).id == 1156).Send("Hey 1156!");
```

You just need to do `typecast` and then usual query works fine.